# Multiple inheritance and the this pointer

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, reinterpret-cast

Suppose I have this struct:

```
struct vector_data
{
    double x, y;

    double& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return * (static_cast<double*>(static_cast<void*>(this)) + index);
    }
};
```

The operator[] should work as expected, because vector_data is a POD type.
The expected behaviour is that vector_data[0] returns x, and vector_data[1] returns y.

Now suppose I have a second struct:

```
struct more_data
{
    double evil_data;

    // There could be more here, data or functions
};
```

And derive from both like this:

```
struct composed : public more_data, public vector_data
{
};
```

Will this destory the expected behaviour of operator[]? In other words, will the this-pointer of vector_data in the derived struct still point to the vector_data part of the struct, or will it point to the beginning of the derived struct?

If it does destroy operator[], then how can I resolve this problem? I can inherit from vector_data first, but suppose composed contains virtual functions. I know most compilers put the vtable at the end, but this is not guaranteed. What would be the best approach?

Comment: You're doing pointer arithmetics on a `void*`, what should work as expected exactly (or rather what do you mean by expected)?

Comment: See edit. This is just an example of a more generic question though: what does the this-pointer point to?

Comment: I understand it's just and example, but arithmetics on `void*` pointers is not defined, the inner cast is useless.

Comment: Sometimes the compiler complains that it cannot cast a pointer of type x to type y, so casting to a void pointer first resolves that problem.

Comment: Can't you just return x or y based on the value of index?

Comment: Ah Mat, now I see what you meant with incorrect arithmetics. I forgot the ).

Yaniro: yes, I can, but will that be as fast as using an offset?

Comment: "`static_cast<double*>(static_cast<void*>`" why not simply `reinterpret_cast`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leaving aside the issues of your incorrect pointer arithmetics (the possibility of padding between `x` and `y` invalidates your assumption), here is a quick illustration of what's going on with `this` pointer when you use multiple inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct a {
    int aa;
    void showA() {
        cerr << this << endl;
    }
};
struct b {
    int bb;
    void showB() {
        cerr << this << endl;
    }
};
struct c : public a, b {
    int cc;
    void showC() {
        cerr << this << endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    c x;
    x.showA();
    x.showB();
    x.showC();
}
```

`showA` and `showB` print different numbers; `showC` prints the same number as `showA`, because `a` is listed first in the list of bases. If you switch `a` and `b` there, then `showC` and `showB` would be the same. The "magic" is in the C++ compiler: it is smart enough to give each member function a correct `this` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is something like:

```
struct vector_data
{
   union 
   {
        struct 
        {
            double x, y;
        }; 
        double data[2];
   }; 

   double& operator[](size_t index)
   {
       return data[index];
   }
}
```

Comment: That is roughly what I wanted to achieve, but the problem with this is that it also exposes the data member.

Comment: Note that unnamed unions and structs that "overflow" their members into the surrounding class are an MSVC extension, not standard C++, and as such unportable.